# What is the difference between "use" and "utilize"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, synonyms

What is the difference between "use" and "utilize"?
Which one is more common?

> utilize : to use something in an effective way
>
> "The vitamins come in a form that is easily utilized by the body."

It is also possible to use "use" in the example. Right?

Comment: Welcome Parisa! Here are some related questions that seem to answer your question. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19811/using-utilize-instead-of-use  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143941/when-to-use-use-and-when-to-use-utilize-in-a-sentence

Comment: Good question. I am confused too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition if you want to use the vitamins in an effective way by the body you'll have to use utilized, if you just want the body to use the vitamins but not in the most optimal way you can use used.

Most people always say use, and in this example the word "easily" gives the impression that the vitamins are utilized, but in a formal and strict environment you'll have to use utilized when referring to an optimal and effective way of something that is used